# Can I install Docker on arm8 based Synology Nas

Tags: docker, synology

I have a Synology Disk Station 118 (appears it is using Arm8 processor)

There is no Docker package found by searching within Package Manager
I found this [article](https://tylermade.net/2017/09/28/how-to-install-docker-on-an-unsupported-synology-nas/) but the link to Synology packages only has X64 packages and article says Docker does not work from Arm

But it does seem from various articles Docker is available from arm8 platforms

https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#architectures-other-than-amd64

and there is a link to unofficial

https://hub.docker.com/u/arm64v8/

but aren't these just containers rather than than the actual docker itself ?

So it is possible to install on my Synology Nas 118. This is required to test a docker file for my application.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer is YES. Any ARM type of Synology NAS supports docker, not completely but it can be enough.
Please follow the steps below to install docker/dockerd in ARM Synology NAS.

1. Download static docker binary at https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/ . Choose the right version for your ARM chip, most likely aarch64 will be the one for your Synology NAS. You can use an old version https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/aarch64/docker-17.09.0-ce.tgz and give it a try, although newer versions could work too.
2. tar xzvf /path/to/.tar.gz
3. sudo cp docker/* /usr/bin/
4. create the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` configuration file with the following configuration:

```
{
  "storage-driver": "vfs",
  "iptables": false,
  "bridge": "none"
}
```

5. sudo dockerd &
6. sudo docker run -d --network=host portainer/portainer:linux-arm64

Please note, you need to set **storage drive vfs, iptables off, bridge off** due to a Linux kernel problem. And you need to run docker container with --network=host mode.
It is not usual, but it is necessary due to Synology NAS kernel limitations.

Or you can have a try with this automatic script:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wdmomoxx/catdriver/master/install-docker.sh

Comment: extra tips: add dockerd to the taskmanager to run on startup and make a docker group and add your user to it to use docker without sudo

Comment: you can easily run out of space for docker since the default dsm / mount is only 2GB, to prevent this you can create a docker folder on your volume, mount it to /docker and set it as data-root:
`sudo mkdir -p /volume1/@Docker/lib` `sudo mkdir /docker` `sudo mount -o bind "/volume1/@Docker/lib" /docker`. Then set the data-root in /etc/docker/daemon.json: `{ "data-root": "/docker" }`

Comment: Whenever I run step #6, I get `/bin/docker: /bin/docker: cannot execute binary file`
Any idea on how to get past that?

Comment: Thank you very much! The linked version (docker-17.09.0-ce.tgz) still works on Synology 220j with the latest DSM.

Comment: @Eptin _"Choose the right version for your ARM chip"_

Comment: `uname -m` shows the architecture of your ARM chip. Just in case of someone needed.

Comment: very usefull and pedagogic. Anyway there's a gist with a complete solution including docker-compose https://gist.github.com/ta264/2b7fb6e6466b109b9bf9b0a1d91ebedc

Comment: Here, to complete the bridge functionality of ARM Synology NAS. The idea can work in all official Synology NAS which have no docker spk.  The main step is just compile the nas kernal and copy needed files to the NAS. 
Refer link: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70529455/docker-in-bridge-network-mode-on-arm-based-synology-nas/72139646

https://www.v2ex.com/t/850768

https://github.com/ourcubk/catdriver

Comment: I have `/usr/bin/dockerd`, but I'm always getting the error `dockerd: command not found` when typing `sudo dockerd &`. What am I missing?

Comment: is there any reason you need the extra copy of the docker files you copied in step 3? Can't you just `mv` the files and save space?

Comment: I managed to do it today on a Synology DS418 as a complete newbie on docker/ssh/linux. I encountered several issues in the process, such as `command not found` as mentioned by @macabeus or `permission denied`. First, ensure that you are in the good folder, i.e. `/usr/bin`. Second, I think newly created files have some sort of permission issue, and so I had to do `chmod +x` on all the files created in the process (e.g., `chmod +x dockerd`, `chmod +x docker`, and so on).

Comment: To know on which files you need to run `sudo chmod +x `, check all white names when you run `ls` in `/usr/bin`.

Last, I also had to create the docker group with `synogroup --add docker root`, I added my username in that group in the DSM interface, and I also ran that command: `chown root:docker /var/run/docker.sock`.

I hope it helps other users who struggled like me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have found ready script for installing docker and docker-compose for ARM NAS:

https://wiki.servarr.com/docker-arm-synology

Answer (score -3):

in the github proyect [docker on arm](https://github.com/alexellis/docker-arm) and you can read in proyect:

```
 No official Docker images work on the ARM architecture because they contain binaries built for x64 (regular PCs).
```

So, you need get source binary from application, and compile to architecture ARM if you need install application.

Comment: There is no point me trying to compile i know nothing about docker, im looking for existing arm8 binaries for Synology

Comment: you [check](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/DS118#specs) say 64 bit architecture. so you not need docker over arm, simply install docker for 64 bit

Comment: It is 64bit, but 64bit ARM not 64bit Intel :(

Comment: Check this article [here](https://blog.alexellis.io/get-started-with-docker-on-64-bit-arm/) , maybe you can run it