# Can I install Docker on Synology DS418?

Tags: docker

Is there a way to install Docker on Synology DS418 ?

I had try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52520008/can-i-install-docker-on-arm8-based-synology-nas) with this [aarch64/docker-20.10.6.tgz](https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/aarch64/).

Here are the step I did:

1. Download static docker binary at https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/aarch64/ . I choose the aarch64/docker-20.10.6.tgz, but I am maybe mistaking here.
2. tar xzvf /path/to/.tar.gz
3. sudo cp docker/* /usr/bin/
4. create the /etc/docker/daemon.json configuration file with the following configuration:

```
{
  "storage-driver": "vfs",
  "iptables": false,
  "bridge": "none"
}
```

5. sudo dockerd &

I received this error when I do the step 5.

```
xxx@NAS:~$ sudo dockerd &
[1] 806
xxx@NAS:~$ INFO[2021-05-04T14:35:55.752149353-05:00] Starting up
WARN[2021-05-04T14:35:55.753236211-05:00] could not change group /var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found
INFO[2021-05-04T14:35:55.753833733-05:00] libcontainerd: containerd is still running pid=28644
INFO[2021-05-04T14:35:55.753946586-05:00] parsed scheme: "unix" module=grpc
INFO[2021-05-04T14:35:55.754184624-05:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme module=grpc
INFO[2021-05-04T14:35:55.754265514-05:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>} module=grpc
INFO[2021-05-04T14:35:55.754313995-05:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first" module=grpc
WARN[2021-05-04T14:35:56.754892127-05:00] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout". Reconnecting... module=grpc
WARN[2021-05-04T14:35:59.191460361-05:00] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout". Reconnecting... module=grpc
WARN[2021-05-04T14:36:03.215171500-05:00] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout". Reconnecting... module=grpc
WARN[2021-05-04T14:36:08.582014438-05:00] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout". Reconnecting... module=grpc
failed to start containerd: timeout waiting for containerd to start
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks for you first question. But can you replace the links you provided by the actual steps you’ve taken? The question will become more clear by that.

Comment: Hi, I edit my question. Can you now understand my question?

Comment: The fifth line of the error message (group docker not found) is a problem. I think that’s because the group hasn’t been created by the install and due to the fact you use a static binary it’s now weird. Because there’s no install. Does a Synology have a package manager? Like Aptitude for Ubuntu. That makes live much easier.

Comment: If you do not know the synology os, you cannot really help me.
The thing I am doing is to bypass the package manager restriction.

Comment: Hi @jeremiebergeron, was your install successfull ? Any other recommendation ?

Comment: Yes, it now work.

Comment: I used dowload manager to download https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/aarch64/docker-20.10.9.tgz
I also used the FileStation to uncompress the thing in to a folder (that looks empty using File Station).
I also managed to connect to the DS418 using ssh. 
Now I am lost :-/  Could you make the explanation above idiot proof please ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what to say more. All the step are there.

Comment: @jeremiebergeron, how is the performance of Docker containers on DS418? Any lag using native Synology services due to high RAM usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you're missing is:

```
sudo synogroup --add docker $USER
```

If you run this command as a non-root user, that user will be able to execute `docker` commands without `sudo`.

If you don't want this, try running the command as `root` or

```
sudo synogroup --add docker
```

may work. But I haven't tested either these latter two approaches.

Comment: I'm assuming this command is intended to be run between steps 4 & 5 in the question?

Comment: Yes, that's correct