# Docker on Synology DS220j ARMv8

Tags: docker, synology, armv8, configuration-files

I have tried to instal Docker on Synology DS220j as mentioned here:

1. [Can I install Docker on arm8 based Synology Nas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52520008/can-i-install-docker-on-arm8-based-synology-nas)
2. https://cynarski.eu/docker-on-synlogy-32bit/

When executing the dockerd I get this error “the following directives don't match any configuration option: storage/driver" [Error Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O85IW.png)

I think I have a problem on the config file even if I have done it exactly as mentioned.
What can be the problem here?