# Docker in bridge network mode on ARM-based Synology NAS?

Tags: docker, networking, synology

I have an ARM64-based Synology NAS device and have been trying to set up Docker on it using the instructions found here:

[Can I install Docker on arm8 based Synology Nas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52520008/can-i-install-docker-on-arm8-based-synology-nas)

However, the fact that I can't use the default bridge network mode but instead have to use host mode (`network_mode=host`) is preventing me from doing some things that I'd like to do. In the aforementioned thread user [P Leo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12319635/p-leo) writes:

> Please note, you need to set storage drive vfs, iptables off, bridge
> off due to a Linux kernel problem. And you need to run docker
> container with --network=host mode. It is not usual, but it is
> necessary due to Synology NAS kernel limitations.

I was wondering if anyone could shed more light on this apparent limitation? Based on other Synology- and Docker-related discussions online, it seems that it doesn't affect some users. Is the issue perhaps limited to ARM-based devices or specific Linux kernel versions (my device has 4.4.180+)? And most importantly, is there really no way around it?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this recently on a DS218 that has an arm64 (RTD1296) CPU. It's a bit involved but doable.

**Start Docker in `bridge` Mode**

First thing, check if your NAS has the necessary kernel modules in `/usr/lib/modules`. Mine did, so load them in this order:

```
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/veth.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/stp.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/tun.ko
# sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/nf_defrag_ipv4.ko # Already loaded for me
# sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/nf_conntrack.ko
# sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/x_tables.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/xt_TCPMSS.ko
# sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/xt_recent.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/xt_NFQUEUE.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/xt_mark.ko
# sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/xt_mac.ko
# sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/xt_limit.ko
# sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/xt_iprange.ko
# sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/xt_geoip.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/xt_addrtype.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/xt_conntrack.ko
# sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/xt_LOG.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/bridge.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/br_netfilter.ko
# sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/xt_state.ko
# sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/xt_tcpudp.ko
# sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/xt_multiport.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/nf_nat.ko
# sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/nf_conntrack_ipv4.ko
# sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/ip_tables.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/nf_nat_redirect.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/xt_REDIRECT.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/xt_nat.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/nf_nat_ipv4.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/ipt_MASQUERADE.ko
# sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/iptable_filter.ko
  sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/iptable_nat.ko
```

(If you see a `File Exists` error, ignore it; it just means the module has already been loaded.)

Then check if `iptables` can match by `addrtype` or `conntrack` since `dockerd` needs both.

```
iptables -m addrtype -h
iptables -m conntrack -h
```

If you see an error such as `No such file or directory`, you have work to do. You can either install a version of `iptables` that's not crippled from [Entware](https://github.com/Entware/Entware/wiki/Install-on-Synology-NAS) (`opkg install iptables`), or you can compile the missing libs yourself. I did the latter on my Mac:

```
% docker run --name=ubuntu -it --rm --platform linux/arm64 --entrypoint bash ubuntu:latest
% apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential bc bison flex vim wget xz-utils
% mkdir /syno && cd /syno
### Note: version 1.6.0 was shipped with my NAS
% wget https://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/files/iptables-1.6.0.tar.bz2
### Note: also needed these dependent packages
% wget https://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnftnl/files/libnftnl-1.0.5.tar.bz2
% wget https://www.netfilter.org/projects/libmnl/files/libmnl-1.0.3.tar.bz2
% tar -xjf *.tar.bz2
% cd iptables-1.6.0
% cp ../libnftnl-1.0.5/include/libnftnl include/
% cp ../libmnl-1.0.3/include/libmnl include/
% ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/syno
% make
% find /syno -name libxt_*so
```

The compile failed for me, but it produced the 2 libs `libxt_addrtype.so` and `libxt_conntrack.so` I needed. Copy them to `/usr/lib/iptables/` on your NAS, the 2 commands above should run without errors.

And now `dockerd` should be able to start successfully with bridge network:

```
sudo cat <<EOF >/etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "storage-driver": "vfs",
    "bip": "172.16.0.1/16",
    "default-gateway": "172.16.0.254"
}
EOF
sudo /bin/dockerd &
```

**Turn on IP Forwarding and Configure Firewall**

To be able to communicate with your containers from your LAN, you also need to do these to allow IP forwarding:

```
# Turn on IP forwarding
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
# Allow containers to access Docker socket
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

And finally, open up your firewall to allow access to the ports. Assuming you have `-p 8080:80` for a container, you'll need to open port `8080` for your LAN the NAS is in (eg. `192.168.0.0/24`).

**Configure a Proxy**

With the above though, what I found was, if I ran a container with published ports, I still could only reach the server via `localhost`, but not via the LAN IP of my NAS.

```
sudo docker run \
    --name=nginx-test \
    --rm \
    --network=bridge \
    -e PUID=`id -u $USER` \
    -e PGID=`id -g $USER` \
    -p 8080:80 \
    -v /volume1/docker/nginx:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro \
    -v /dev:/dev \
    nginx:latest

curl localhost:8080    # This succeeded
curl 192.168.0.10:8080 # This timed out
```

Docker was supposed to [take care of this](https://windsock.io/the-docker-proxy/) for me, but somehow it didn't.

So I needed a proxy to forward packets (TCP in addition to HTTP/S, in my use case) between `192.168.0.10:8080` and `localhost:8080`. I opted to use `nginx` because I couldn't get either `iptables` or `docker-proxy` to work, but I had to change my LAN access to a new port, ie. `192.168.0.10:8081`.

```
opkg install nginx # Needed v1.9, the one shipped was too old
cat <<EOF >/opt/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user nobody users;
stream {
    upstream server_8080 {
        server localhost:8080;
    }
    server {
        listen 8081;
        proxy_pass server_8080;
    }
}
sudo /opt/etc/init.d/S80nginx start
```

Finally after also changing the open port in firewall to `8081`, `curl 192.168.0.10:8081` worked.

**PS.** If someone could tell me why `iptables` or `docker-proxy` didn't forward ports between `localhost` and my LAN IP, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks very much for this! I was able to use the instructions to get a container running in bridge mode, but I also encountered the same issue with the container being inaccessible via the LAN IP. I don't have nginx set up in quite the same way as in the instructions, so I'm not able to use the same proxy solution, but hopefully someone will suggest another way around the issue.

Comment: If you just need to forward HTTP/S traffic, you can use Synology's reverse proxy: Control Panel -> Application Portals -> Reverse Proxy.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have a domain name and my goal isn't so much to expose the dockerized service to the wider internet, but to be able to access it from within my LAN...

Comment: A reverse proxy configured on Synology exposes your dockerized service to your LAN.

Comment: Ah, indeed, thanks! I didn't know what to put in as hostname, but * did the trick. :-)

Comment: Would it work if I actually can’t access Internet from within a conatiner?

Comment: It depends on why the container can't access the internet. If the internet is blocked off at your router, it doesn't affect how you configure docker inside Synology.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **Yes** that you **Can** use completely docker functionality on ARM-based Synology NAS, including bridge functionality.

Before you use it, you need complete the missed .ko driver files for the Synology NAS linux kernel.

You can follow the steps in https://www.v2ex.com/t/850768#reply2 to complete all missed .ko files. Then you can run Docker with full functionality on ARM-based Synology NAS.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! I couldn't directly use the files provided in the link, but I'll try to somehow cross-compile the source files for my Synology NAS. Any help there would be most appreciated!