# Detailed Step by Step for Installing Docker on Synology DS120j (aarch64)?

Tags: docker, arm64, synology, home-assistant, homebridge

I have scrubbed the internet for detailed instructions on how to install Docker specifically on a Synology DS120j (aarch64, running DSM 7.1.4) and still need some help.
For confirmation I checked,

```
uname -m
```

aarch64

I'm seeing that it looks to be possible to in stall Docker on this non-Intel machine but so far the instructions I've read are not as specific (step by step) as I apparently need them to be because something's not quite working.

End use is installing and running Home Assistant on this machine (which requires Docker) as an alternative to Raspberry Pi 4 because they are so hard to find and the DS120j seems to be an economic alternative (I have Homebridge successfully running on it and it's working great).

Though it looks like I was able to (sort of) install Docker, I can not access the Docker GUI / it does not show up in my package center. I'm not sure how I can install Home Assistant without the Docker GUI.

So I'm not sure if what I've done right and wrong along the way but have tried multiple methods  (from 4 post on Stackoverflow) to get to this point but I might need to start from scratch, which I'm completely prepared to do!

I have tried steps  1 - 6 from this Stackoverflow post including trying the automatic script (and also a second automatic script from a link that was posted further down the in the post replies).
[Can I install Docker on arm8 based Synology Nas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52520008/can-i-install-docker-on-arm8-based-synology-nas)

Any detailed step by step instructions or insigts would be greatly appreciated.
I have held off for two weeks posting about this but am doing so now because there seems to be a lot of people buying these cheap DS120j NAS machines to run Homebridge / Home Assistant and other servers in place of Raspberry Pi's.

Thank you!
M

This is one script that I have tried:

```
#!/bin/sh
#/bin/wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wdmomoxx/catdriver/master/install-docker.sh | /bin/sh
/bin/wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wdmomoxx/catdriver/master/catdsm-docker.tgz
tar -xvpzf catdsm-docker.tgz -C /
rm catdsm-docker.tgz
PATH=/opt/sbin:/opt/bin:/opt/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
/opt/etc/init.d/S60dockerd
sudo docker run -d --network=host -v "/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"  portainer/portainer:linux-arm64
echo "猫盘群晖Docker安装完成"
echo "浏览器输入群晖IP:9000进入Docker UI"
```

also

```
sudo mkdir -p /volume1/@Docker/lib
```

```
sudo mkdir /docker
```

```
sudo mount -o bind "/volume1/@Docker/lib" /docker
```

This tip from comments in the above Stackoverflow post, I do not understand though,

"Then set the data-root in /etc/docker/daemon.json: { "data-root": "/docker" }"

I have also created a docker user group and added my name to the group but I'm not sure if docker is set to associate the two.

However when I currently ssh into the Diskstation and

```
docker --version"
```

I do get,

Docker version 20.10.0, build 7287ab3

but I can not seem to see or launch the Docker GUI.

I see there is talk on the next about using Portainer but I'm not sure how to get that running as well.

Comment: "*I see there is talk on the next about using Portainer but I'm not sure how to get that running as well.*" - `docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9000:9000 --name=portainer --restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer-ce`, when the container has started, access `http://localhost:9000`

Comment: Hi,  thanks for responding!   The above command returned the following :      
docker: invalid reference format.